# Как установить Turbo Pascal на Linux?

Tags: pascal, linux

Пытался установить TP7 на школьный Линукс. Сразу же скачал эмулятор dosbox. Если скачиваешь *.exe. Wine грузит его и грузит, но в конце концов он просто прекращает загрузку dosbox'а. Скачивал архивы для Линукса, а там не понятно как им пользоватся, как установить его и т.п. Народ кто знает что делать подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Отметьте уже ответ и закройте тему. Слишком много некропостеров.

Comment: очень связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444224/178576

Answer (score 5):

Поставьте [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) это бесплатный аналог для линукса

Comment: Это больше чем аналог. Но он как минимум не хуже.

Comment: Он даже лучше :-)

Answer (score 0):

Я в целом присоединяюсь к тем, кто посоветовал поставить FreePascal. Это хороший компилятор. Да и в родной среде конечно же лучше работать, чем на эмуляторе.

Однако если Ваш преподаватель упорно требует именно Turbo Pascal (а я такое в принципе допускаю), позволю себе маленькое замечание. По Вашему лаконичному сообщению и упоминанию Wine я заподозрил, что Вы пытаетесь скачать DOSBox для Windows и запустить его под Wine, то есть эмулятор под эмулятором. Делать этого совершенно не нужно - для линукса есть "родная" версия DOSBox, а также ещё один эмулятор - DOSEmu. Под ними и надо запускать ДОСовские программы. Wine здесь не нужен, он для другого.

Говоря про "школьный Линукс", Вы имеете в виду Альт Линукс 5.0 Школьный? Или что-то ещё?

UPD

> Скачивал архивы для Линукса, а там не понятно как им пользоватся, как установить его и т.п.

А! Этого сразу не заметил. Архивы DOSBox-а имеются в виду, я так полагаю? Ну тогда надо уточнять, какой именно архив Вы качали - исходники в tar.bz2 или что-то ещё. И в зависимости от этого двигаться дальше. Но в любом случае это - правильный путь. А запускать виндовую версию DOSBox в wine - ложный.

Answer (score 0):

если на машине уже установленны и вайн и борланд паскаль то пробуйте писать не wine, а wineconsole

пример
wineconsole bp.exe

Answer (score 0):

Если коротко, то:

1. Устанавливаем DOSBox через терминал (для debian):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dosbox
   ```
2. Скачиваем Turbo Pascal для windows.
3. Запускаем DOSBox через терминал, выполнив команду dosbox.
4. Монтируем папку с Turbo Pascal через командную строку DOSBox:

   ```
   mount d ~/turbopascal
   d:
   ```

   Первая команда монтирует папку ~/turbopascal как виртуальный диск D внутри DOSBox. Вторая команда переключает текущий диск из Z: на D:.
5. Запускаем Turbo Pascal, введя в командной строке названание исполняемого файла.

Comment: вообще-то ссылки на мусорные сайты у нас тут не приветствуются. p.s. продвижению вашего сайта его упоминание здесь никак не поможет, а вот люди, перейдя по ссылке, и обнаружив вонючую помойку, вряд ли этому будут рады.