# Pascal на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pascal

Как компилировать Pascal и в чем лучше писать на Ubuntu?
Желательно что-нибудь минималистичное

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

например, так:

1. устанавливаем компилятор *freepascal*:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install fp-compiler
   ```
2. создаём файл `hw.pas` следующего содержимого:

   ```
   program hello;
   begin
     writeln ('hello, world.')
   end.
   ```
3. компилируем:

   ```
   $ fpc hw.pas
   ...
   ```
4. запускаем получившийся бинарник `hw`:

   ```
   $ ./hw
   hello, world.
   ```

Comment: Хороший способ) но я использовал проще) брал старый любимый free pascal, грузил на убунту, запускал через wine, все

Comment: @ДенисКотляров, это и есть [freepascal](http://www.freepascal.org/). причём нативный, без каких-либо эмуляторов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще использовать Geany.

Выполнить установку этой программы можно через терминал. Для этого собственно нужно открыть терминал, через систему, или зажать клавиши Ctrl+Alt+T.

В открывшемся окне нужно вписать скрип установки программы:

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

Затем ввести пароль системы, после чего подождать окончания установки.
Теперь казалось бы программа установлена, и можно начинать работать, однако без компилятора сделать программы толком невозможно. Поэтому следующим шагом, через терминал установим ещё и компилятор для паскаля.

```
sudo apt-get install fp-compiler
```

Снова вводим пароль, соглашаемся с установкой и ждём её окончания.

На этом всё, запускаем программу Geany

Компилируем через F8, и запускаем через F5. Как видно, компилятор работает.

Взято с:
http://informat45.mybb.ru/viewtopic.php?id=296

Answer (score 0):

Я рекомендую Lazarus, удобная IDE, которая использует freepascal